Size of Dataset object
I defined a dataset as below
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset

class Datagen(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, value, label):
        self.value = value
        self.label = label

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        data = torch.tensor([self.value])
        label = torch.tensor([self.label])
        return data, label

dataset = Datagen(value=1, label=10)

print(dataset[50000])

and found that there's no limit to the index.
can anyone explain the mechanism of Dataset object??
and what happens if we make a dataloader as below?
dataloader = data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=2000)

Does the dataloader owns its size?

Programming questions (including asking about how an API or library works) are off-topic here. See https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Oh I didn't know it. Thanks for noticing.

When working with the Pytorch Dataset, we need to implement not just __getitem__ but also __len__. When we implement __len__ Pytorch uses it for things such as computing how many batches it can make given a batch size and a dataset size. If we request a batch size larger than the dataset size, Pytorch will simply return to us the max-size it can. So if our dataset is of length 10, and we request a batch size of 100, we will actually just get 10.
In your case, your __getitem__ takes an index, but does not appear to use it. So you can pass in 10000000000000 it's still just going to return self.value and self.label each as a tensor. You need to implement the method so that it actually uses the index to fetch a specific instance.

it seems that adding len does not limit the index. I added
def len
return 20000
and index 50000 still works. should i do something more?

Would it be possible to update the code snippet on your question so I can see what you're working with :)?
